# Error while adding new field in Solr with default value

Tags: solr

I am trying to add new field in Solr with default value but getting below error. I am sure that I am using wrong key for default but not able to get correct key in Google.

**Command**

```
curl -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"name": "ALL_MODE_INDC","stored": true,"indexed": true,"field_type": "string" ,"default":"N"}' http://<solrServer>:<solrIP>/api/collections/ALGORITHM_AU_TEST/fields
```

**Error message**

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Unknown or dissallowed key found:default","code":"error.forbidden.key","key":"default"}],"http_status_name":"Unprocessable Entity","http_status_code":422}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution (change key name to "default_value") -

```
curl -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"name": "ALL_MODE_INDC","stored": true,"indexed": true,"field_type": "string" ,"default_value":"N"}' http://<solrServer>:<solrIP>/api/collections/ALGORITHM_AU_TEST/fields
```